# LogBlackmagicCore: Error: A DeckLink iterator could not be created - 80040154

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

Hey can someone help me?

When I try packaging my project I get this error:

LogBlackmagicCore: Error: A DeckLink iterator could not be created - 80040154. The DeckLink drivers may not be installed.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error

I dont use BlackmagicCore, dont know what it is. New to all of this

Thanks :)

I managed to sort out other error. had succsess, but this one IDK